# How can I save CSV file into a mysql table column using php?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Hi I would like to know if there is a way to save a CSV file into a mysql table column using php? Please see that I am not seeking answers for importing/export data to & from table to csv file, I need to save the entire file after exporting from somewhere into a table. say for example:

```
id date       file
1 8/16/2022   abc.csv
2 7/16/2022   xyz.csv
```

I have everything till the point of data insertion. Just need someone to guide me on how to insert the file into table column using php, am using codeigniter.

Comment: You mean put the entire contents of the CSV into a database field? Yes, that's possible, just make sure that the field is large enough to hold the data.

Comment: Yes entire contents of the CSV into a database field, I am planning to use text as datatype for the file size isn't too large @HonkderHase

Comment: Then it's treated like any other string basically...

Comment: You can also use the [LOAD_FILE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file).

Comment: It's not going to be usable in database but `file_get_contents` should allow you to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, it should be fairly simple. Assuming you already have a PDO object called `$dbh`, something similar to this should work (not verified):

```
$myStringContainingTheWholeFirstCsv = file_get_contents('abc.csv');
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `my_table_name` (`my_column_name`) VALUES (:csv)');
$sth->bindParam(':csv', $myStringContainingTheWholeFirstCsv, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: Note that the size of the CSV file must be smaller than the  `max_allowed_packet` MySQL option, and that option is effectively the lesser value set by the client and the MySQL Server.

Comment: Good point. `file_get_contents()` always holds the possibility of danger.